# String To integer JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to get the integer in this string `xyzabc123`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to add to [alex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871216/string-to-integer-javascript/4871229#4871229) if you wanted to get a functional integer

```
var number = 'xyzabc123'.replace(/[^\d]+/, '');
number = parseInt(number,10);
```

Comment: What do you mean by a *functional integer*?

Comment: I mean a value of actual integer type, you're example does not convert a string to an integer, it changes a string to a string (of number characters).

Comment: you should always use a radix with parseInt, e.g. `parseInt(number, 10)` otherwise some numbers, beginning with 0 for example, will be converted incorrectly.

Answer (score 4):

You can replace everything that is not a number with a regex...

```
var number = 'xyzabc123'.replace(/[^\d]+/g, '');
```

[See it on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/ynNVq).

#### Update

To protect yourself from a string like this: `b0ds72` which will be interpreted as octal, use `parseInt()` (or `Number()`; `Number` is JavaScript's number type, like a `float`.)

```
number = parseInt(number, 10);
```

Comment: what is the ending g in your regular expression

Comment: @Web Developer Global match flag.

Comment: @Web Developer It will keep matching to the end of the string, not on first match.